# jQuery multiple filters by class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am building an filter option with multiple filters option. I want to filter on classes but I can’t get it working. I manage to create multiple filters. These filters can also be combined. But if you then adjust/change one of these filters the results do not want to update.

- First change filter 1
- Than change filter 2 (location)
- If you now change filter 1 again (with filter 2 not changed) it don’t update the results.

```js
$('select').change(function() {
  var current = this.value;
  $.each($('#FilterContainer').find('div.all').not('.hidden').not('.' + current), function() {
    $(this).addClass('hidden');
  });
  $.each($('#FilterContainer').find('div.all').is('.' + current), function() {
    $(this).removeClass('hidden');
  });
});
```

```css
.hidden { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Filter:</p>
<select class="filterby">
  <option value="all"><h5>Show All</h5></option>
  <option value="1"><h5>One</h5></option>
  <option value="2"><h5>Two</h5></option>
  <option value="3"><h5>Three</h5></option>
</select>
<p>Location:</p>
<select class="filterby">
  <option value="all"><h5>All Locations</h5></option>
  <option value="nj"><h5>NJ</h5></option>
  <option value="ny"><h5>NY</h5></option>
  <option value="pa"><h5>PA</h5></option>
</select>
<div id="FilterContainer">
  <div class="all 1 nj">Test One NJ</div>
  <div class="all 1 ny">Test One NY</div>
  <div class="all 1 pa">Test One PA</div>
  <div class="all 2 nj">Test Two NJ</div>
  <div class="all 2 ny">Test Two NY</div>
  <div class="all 2 pa">Test Two PA</div>
  <div class="all 3 nj">Test Three NJ</div>
  <div class="all 3 ny">Test Three NY</div>
  <div class="all 3 pa">Test Three PA</div>
</div>
```

(or on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Q5DpP/5/))

Comment: Please always try to add a [mcve] in the question itself (preferable as snippet -> `<>` / Ctrl+M) and not only a link to an external resource that may be not available (offline, blocked, ...).

Comment: The "filter" selects have invalid markup. [`<option>`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html50/forms.html#the-option-element) nodes can only have [Text](https://www.w3.org/TR/html50/dom.html#text-content) (text nodes and [phrasing content](https://www.w3.org/TR/html50/dom.html#phrasing-content-1)) but no heading elements.

Comment: Hi Andreas,

Sorry I am new here and have to discover it yet. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @morrits assign ids to your select dropdowns to make life easier. otherwise the value of 'this' can confuse things. Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/ejsnu3bq/

Comment: No problem :) You are welcome

Comment: Hi @RachelGallen It seems that it is not working properly.
If I do the first click on filter 1, nothing happens and if I first use another filter and then filter 1, it works.

And finally, if I want a third filter (for example Countries) how can I achieve this? I guess on the same way. But I can't get it working.

Comment: Sorry used enter to early. See my comment above. You can check the option with a country filter here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56314940/jquery-multiple-filters-by-class?answertab=oldest#tab-top

Comment: @morrits it's only meant to be a starting point (otherwise I'd have posted an answer).  sO isn't a code writing service, I'm sure you can improve on it. I'm making food at the minute. I'm sure you take the point of assigning individual IDs makes it easier to retrieve accurate values anyway.

Comment: @RachelGallen yes, you are right. I'm going to play with it! Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to reset all the elements on each user interaction by removing .hidden class. At the top of your .change() function, try this:

```
.removeClass('hidden');
```

Once you remove .hidden from all the elements, you can add the class to the elements that need it.

In the JSFiddle example, you can write this this way:

```
$('select').change(function () {
    var current = this.value;
    $.each($('#FilterContainer').find('div.all'), function () {
        $(this).removeClass('hidden');
    });

    $.each($('#FilterContainer').find('div.all').not('.' + current), function () {
        $(this).addClass('hidden');
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick respons. Appreciate it!
Sorry I included the wrong code in the post. See the jsfiddle for example or the (new)code above.